# crm2011, javascript onchange event system entity

Tags: javascript, entity, system, dynamics-crm-2011, onchange

I'm new to CRM2011 and can, but I have been given a task that I don't know how to solve and didn't find any answers in Google.

I've 2 entities. Case and Notes (Annotation - system entity). Notes is related to the case and represented by area on a form where users can add their notes. After a new note has been added I need to run a JS. How can I do it? I can not assign onchange event, because it's system entity and I can't modify anything there, even choose OnChange Event.  I can't set event handler on a case form for this note. Properties blocked as well. If I send event handler onchange area where s not property embedded.

Does anyone know how to run JS on a change of related system property to the form?

Thank you

Comment: What kind of logic is it you want to run? Is it possible to do it with a plugin instead?

Answer (score 2):

I believe that, depending on the exact details of your task at hand, you might want to use a plugin instead. The downside is that you won't be using JavaScript but C# (if you haven't build a plugin before you're in for a treat). The upside is that you won't be using JavaScript but C#.

You might want to intercept the messages of *Create* on the entity *Note* or the message of *Update* on the entity *Case*.

Could you, please, elaborate on what is the goal?